# Parsing web page with HtmlAgilityPack and simulate a click

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I am scraping a certain web page using HAP, and I want to access the submit button on the page but the problem is I don't know how it could be done in HAP and C#, is there a way I could do this?

Comment: So far with my experience, it can not be done with HAP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The HTML Agility Pack is not a browser, so while it can parse an HTML file, there is no way to really interact with it. You can find the `submit` object, read its properties and so forth, but you can't make it do anything.

You have two options:

- Either read the form, build a Http Request object that matches the forms fields and post method and send it to the server. This is all manual work. The Agility Pack only helps you list the fields on the form and their properties
- If you need to interact with the page you'll need a browser. There are headless browsers, like PhantomJS, that will actually load the page, parse the Javascript and run what's sent by the server. There are wrappers around those wrappers for C#, one of [such examples is Awesonium](http://www.awesomium.com/). It's similar to the HTML Agility Pack in that it allows you to parse HTML documents, but it takes it one step further, actually running it without ever showing a browser screen.

Comment: > build a Http Request object that matches the forms fields

I agree with Jesse. You can use Fiddler to record the HTML exchanges between your computer and the server, in a real browser based session, where you physically click the 'submit' button and see what gets sent back to the server. This helps to make it easier to mimic this exchange through C#. This might of course fail if the server generates anti forgery tickets, meaning you cannot always just resubmit the same values (except for a few that you would have changed). This makes Awesonium awesome!